# How to install MySQL 8.1 in Debian 11

Tags: linux, debian, mysql, debian-bullseye

I need MySQL 8.1 for Magento, but I am unable to install it from the given repository.

After some research, I found that the MySQL package has been removed from the default repository and updated with MariaDB instead.

Still, I need MySQL Version 8.1 but I am unable to find any repository.

Does anybody know how to install MySQL 8.1?

Comment: Have you seen https://computingforgeeks.com/how-to-install-mysql-on-debian-ubuntu/, where they give sources for packages and for binaries? Your question would be improved by showing where you *did* look.

Comment: thanks, it worked